# when installing GreenPipes 1.0.9 getting error

Tags: .net-4.0, nuget-package, masstransit, nuget-package-restore

When i try to install GreenPipes  1.0.9 on .net 4.0  project , it is giving me error.

[image]

But Nuget site say it have no dependency [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GreenPipes/1.0.9)  ..

[image]

i need this for [MassTransit 3.5.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit/3.5.7) .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit requires .NET 4.5.2 as the minimal version. If your project is still on .NET 4.0, it won't work for you.

Comment: i am using old version (MassTransit 3.5.7 ), old version also not work on .net 4?

Comment: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/v3.5.7/src/MassTransit/MassTransit.csproj#L18 target version 4.5.2